# SQL Mirgations - Domain Trusts or not to Trust?

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, sql, sql-server-2014

I am about to migrate something like 18 SQL servers into AWS from an on prem\colo. We will be building a new Domain in AWS and would like to leave the old domains behind. Do I need to setup a domain trust in order for my SQL servers to have no downtime? Currently setup in a fail over mirrored configuration. I was planning to do a series of domain trusts so I can flatten out our Domain structure but I am not sure what best practices are when leaving an old domain for a new one. The only thing that really uses Windows service accounts are our SQL DB servers. Is there any where else I might find a trust useful? Any information at all is useful. Thank you so much!

Windows Server 12 R2 + SQL 14 Standard

Comment: It's hard to say based on the information you're providing.  The only thing I can think of off the top of my head is logins.  Are you using Windows authentication for any of the users?  Do you think you might in the future?